# Is filling 1040NR sufficient for Crypto gains for an F-1 student?

Tags: united-states, taxes, f1-student-visa, cryptocurrency

On F-1 status since last 16 months. I have gains of less than $100 on Crypto. Transactions were made on Coinbase.com portal in the US. Other income sources include an Internship on my CPT. Is filing the crypto gains as Capital gains on the 1040NR (page 4) sufficient? Do I need to attach any other form/schedules or file seperately

Answer (score 1):

Depends. If you're a nonresident alien then you do not owe any capital gains in the United States. You have to, however, fill out schedule NEC for any gains/losses from the exchanges not connected to US based businesses or trades. But if you're a resident alien, then you do.